# Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product Override's not working

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, core, resource-model

I'm trying to override the class Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product but it always use the core file. Could you please tell me what's wrong ? Thanks

**app/code/local/Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml:**

```
<config>
    [...]
    <global>
        [...]
        <models>
          <catalog>
              <rewrite>
                  <config>Namespace_Module_Model_Config</config>
                  <category>Namespace_Module_Model_Category</category>
                  <layer>Namespace_Module_Model_Layer</layer>
              </rewrite>
          </catalog>
          <catalog_resource>
              <rewrite>
                  <category>Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_Category</category>
                  <product>Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_Product</product>
              </rewrite>
          </catalog_resource>
       </models>
    </global>
    [...]
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Model/Resource/Product.php:**

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product
{
    protected function _saveCategories(Varien_Object $object)
    {    
        /**
         * If category ids data is not declared we haven't do manipulations
         */
        if (!$object->hasCategoryIds()) {
            return $this;
        }
        $categoryIds = $object->getCategoryIds();
        $oldCategoryIds = $this->getCategoryIds($object);

        $object->setIsChangedCategories(false);

        $insert = array_diff($categoryIds, $oldCategoryIds);
        $delete = array_diff($oldCategoryIds, $categoryIds);

        $write = $this->_getWriteAdapter();
        if (!empty($insert)) {
            $data = array();
            foreach ($insert as $categoryId) {
                if (empty($categoryId)) {
                    continue;
                }
                $data[] = array(
                    'category_id' => (int)$categoryId,
                    'product_id'  => (int)$object->getId(),
                    'position'    => 500  // HERE'S WHAT I WANT TO CUSTOMIZE
                );
            }
            if ($data) {                   
                $write->insertMultiple($this->_productCategoryTable, $data);
            }
        }

        if (!empty($delete)) {
            foreach ($delete as $categoryId) {
                $where = array(
                    'product_id = ?'  => (int)$object->getId(),
                    'category_id = ?' => (int)$categoryId,
                );

                $write->delete($this->_productCategoryTable, $where);
            }
        }

        if (!empty($insert) || !empty($delete)) {
            $object->setAffectedCategoryIds(array_merge($insert, $delete));
            $object->setIsChangedCategories(true);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And I've also override the Model_Resource_Category, but this one is correctly working ! For reference:

**app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Model/Resource/Category.php:**

```
<?php
class Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_Category extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category
{
    protected function _saveCategoryProducts($category)
    {
        $category->setIsChangedProductList(false);
        $id = $category->getId();
        /**
         * new category-product relationships
         */
        $products = $category->getPostedProducts();

        /**
         * Example re-save category
         */
        if ($products === null) {
            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * old category-product relationships
         */
        $oldProducts = $category->getProductsPosition();

        $insert = array_diff_key($products, $oldProducts);
        $delete = array_diff_key($oldProducts, $products);

        /**
         * Find product ids which are presented in both arrays
         * and saved before (check $oldProducts array)
         */
        $update = array_intersect_key($products, $oldProducts);
        $update = array_diff_assoc($update, $oldProducts);

        $adapter = $this->_getWriteAdapter();

        /**
         * Delete products from category
         */
        if (!empty($delete)) {
            $cond = array(
                'product_id IN(?)' => array_keys($delete),
                'category_id=?' => $id
            );
            $adapter->delete($this->_categoryProductTable, $cond);
        }

        /**
         * Add products to category
         */
        if (!empty($insert)) {
            $data = array();
            foreach ($insert as $productId => $position) {
                $data[] = array(
                    'category_id' => (int)$id,
                    'product_id'  => (int)$productId,
                    'position'    => empty($position)?500:(int)$position
                );
            }
            $adapter->insertMultiple($this->_categoryProductTable, $data);
        }

        /**
         * Update product positions in category
         */
        if (!empty($update)) {
            foreach ($update as $productId => $position) {
                $where = array(
                    'category_id = ?'=> (int)$id,
                    'product_id = ?' => (int)$productId
                );
                $bind  = array('position' => empty($position)?500:(int)$position);
                $adapter->update($this->_categoryProductTable, $bind, $where);
            }
        }

        if (!empty($insert) || !empty($delete)) {
            $productIds = array_unique(array_merge(array_keys($insert), array_keys($delete)));
            Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_category_change_products', array(
                'category'      => $category,
                'product_ids'   => $productIds
            ));
        }

        if (!empty($insert) || !empty($update) || !empty($delete)) {
            $category->setIsChangedProductList(true);

            /**
             * Setting affected products to category for third party engine index refresh
             */
            $productIds = array_keys($insert + $delete + $update);
            $category->setAffectedProductIds($productIds);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Any idea why it is working with Model/Resource/Category.php and not Model/Resource/Product.php ?

**EDIT:**
Here's my module declaration (just in case) where I declare the core Catalog module as a dependency.

**app/etc/Namespace_Module.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog/>
                <Unirgy_DropshipMicrosite/>
            </depends>
        </Namespace_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you check to see if any other module is rewriting Product.php?

Comment: I just looked for "<catalog_resource>" in all the files of my project, and it finds only **app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml** and **app/code/local/Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml**. I assume no other module rewrite this file then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after a few more investigations, it appears that it is another class which is used from the Unirgy Dropship plugin.

I don't have the whole picture, but I had to override the class `app/code/community/Unirgy/DropshipVendorProduct/Model/Mysql4/Product.php` which extends `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product` which extends `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product`.

It is really tricky but in the end, overriding this file was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way. Make sure your Product.php file is exist in correct folder structure.

```
        <models>
            <module>
                <class>Namespace_Module_Model</class>
            </module>
            <catalog_resource>
                <rewrite>
                    <product>Namespace_Module_Model_Catalog_Resource_Product</product>
                </rewrite>
            </catalog_resource>
        </models>
```

Also check you have written your class name correct.

Comment: I don't really understand why you want me to put `<product>Namespace_Module_Model_Catalog_Resource_Product</product>`, as the file to override is `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product`.

Comment: it will be ok as you mention in your post "<product>Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_Product</product>".
I want you to try with class declaration.
<class>Namespace_Module_Model</class>

Comment: I did and it didn't work. My file names are also corrects (as you can see it in the code I've put into my initial post)

Comment: Ok. did you check any error in system.log or exception.log files ?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I don't have anything in my system.log or exception.log. The only thing which show up is a solar timeout which is totally irrelevant.

Comment: try to debug in __construct of that class. Also try to clear cache or disable it. can you check compilation is disable in your store.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
...
<models>
    <catalog>
        <rewrite>
            <resource_product>Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_Product</resource_product>
        </rewrite>
    </catalog>
</models>
...
```

It's a bit miss-leading, but a resource model is... well.. a model :)

/Edit: You can see how resources are loaded in the `Mage` class in `app/Mage.php`, `getResourceModel` method which eventually calls `Mage_Core_Model_Config::getResourceModelInstance` bellow:

```
public function getResourceModelInstance($modelClass='', $constructArguments=array())
{
    $factoryName = $this->_getResourceModelFactoryClassName($modelClass);
    if (!$factoryName) {
        return false;
    }
    return $this->getModelInstance($factoryName, $constructArguments);
}
```

Comment: I assume  you wanted to write `<resource_product>Namespace_Module_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product</resource_product>` and you just forgot 'Model'. I've tried that but not working either.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to write; I updated my comment :) Can you post the relevant section of the config.xml here?

Comment: Like @R.S said, can you check if the product resource is overwritten by other modules, this time grepping the xml files for `<resource_product>`? /Edit: Alternatively, somewhere in a script do a `$r = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product'); echo get_class($r) . PHP_EOL;`

Comment: I had also an extra *Catalog* in the path: `Namespace_Module_Model_*Catalog*_Resource_Product`; I updated my answer again.

Comment: What do you mean by "in the path" ? an extra folder in your file system ? adding "Catalog" in the <resource_product> tag ?

Comment: Your file path was `app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Model/Resource/Product.php` and my class name was `Namespace_Module_Model_*Catalog*_Resource_Product`; the class name should have been `Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_Product` to match your file path.

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite code seems correct try to check other module is rewriting this model ?

Create one test file on root of magento copy below code in that and run

```
    require_once("app/Mage.php");
    Mage::app();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r(Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/models/catalog_resource/rewrite'));
```

You will get list of rewrite for catalog_resource

Hope this will help

Comment: Here is the output (which confirm nothing else is overriding those files): `Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element Object
(
    [category] => Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_Category
    [product] => Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_Product
)`

Comment: @christophe
It should work then
now track by echo 
put echo "test from my module" before class
class Namespace_Module_Model_Resource_Product
at 
app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Model/Resource/Product.php

Comment: I already have logs in both files but it still displays the logs in the core file. And I remove the var/cache folder everytime I do a change.